# how to relate two fields of same table in phpmyadmin?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, phpmyadmin

I have created 1 table which stores the `user` and `uid`.

Other table stores the skills of the user:

- If `uid = 111` enters `skill = aaa` it will stored to the skill table but I want when `uid = 111` again enters the `skill = aaa` it should not store in skill table.
- and `uid = 222` enters `skill = aaa` then table will store the value.

Basically I want to relate `uid` and skill fields of skill table so on every unique `uid` there should be unique skill values, but for different `uid`s skill can be same.

Comment: How do you link the skills and the user table? that would determine how this can be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a composite primary key on the two ids `UId` and skill. Also, to make it many to many relation between the two tables, so that each user has many skills, and to  [**normalize**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your tables, better off create it this way:

**`Users`** table:

- `UserID` Primary key,
- `USername`.
- ...

**`Skills`** table:

- `SkillId` Primary key,
- `SkillName`,
- ...

The linkage table:

**`UsersSkills`**:

- `UserId` Foreign key references `Users(UserId)`,
- `SkillId` Foreign key references `Skills(SkillId)`.

And then the important part is to make a composite primary key on `UserId` and `SkillId`, so that the skill is unique for each userid.

In your example, the skill `aaa` would be stored in the `Skills` table with an Id = 1, where the user `UserId = 111` is stored in the `Users` table. Then the `UsersSkills` will contain something like:

```
UserId SkillId
 111   1
```